# creating csv file with perl

Tags: perl

I created csv file with this perl module  Text::CSV_XS on windows:

Below a snippet of my code :

```
use Text::CSV_XS;

my @a =('ID','VALUE'); 


open my $OUTPUT,'>',"file.csv" or die "Can't able to open file.csv\n";

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new ({ binary => 1, eol => $/ });



$csv->print($OUTPUT,\@a);
```

this code generate a file.csv but when I try to open the file.csv with xls the xls write that this file is SYLK and can't know it could someone help why this csv can't open with xls?

Comment: does `file.csv` look like a CSV when you open it in notepad?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This problem occurs when you open a text file or CSV file and the first two characters of the file are the uppercase letters "I" and "D"

["SYLK: File format is not valid" error message when you open file](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323626)

Comment: are you kidding me!! tell me thats an april fools!

Comment: @JoelBerger :) Check the link.. Confirmed by Microsoft

Comment: Incredible! ...and not very slick :-)

Comment: I did, I just can't believe that a real operating system could be that naive. Yikes, that has to be one of the worst gotchas ever!

Comment: @Joel Berger: It's a Excel, not an OS issue. And fwiw, while newer versions than '03 complain they at least load it properly.